# How to get the last occurrence of a date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like the following

| name | birthdate |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1980-10-25 |
| Mike | 1975-09-17 |
| Jill | 1987-01-13 |
| Anne | 1999-02-01 |

Today's date is 2022-02-22.

How would I write a sql query that returns the name and last time their birthday occurred? As in the same day and month from 2022 if their birthday has already happened this year or from 2021 if their birthday hasn't happened this year

Sample response would be

| name | last_birthdate |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2022-10-25 |
| Mike | 2022-09-17 |
| Jill | 2021-01-13 |
| Anne | 2021-02-01 |

Comment: It seems that your expected result is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use date arithmetic:

```
SELECT name,
       birthdate + EXTRACT (year FROM
                            age(current_timestamp, birthdate)
                           ) AS last_birthday
FROM tab;
```

Comment: this doesn't work. date_trunc part should be replaced with EXTRACT(YEAR From AGE(current_timestamp, birthdate))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional:

```
select name, case when date(extract(year from now())||regexp_replace(birthdate::text, '^\d+', '')) < date(now()) then extract(year from now())-1||regexp_replace(birthdate::text, '^\d+', '') else extract(year from now())||regexp_replace(birthdate::text, '^\d+', '') end from people
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    name, 
    case 
        when
            birthdate + concat(extract(YEAR from now()) - extract(YEAR FROM birthdate), ' years')::interval > now()
        then 
            birthdate + concat(extract(YEAR from now()) - extract(YEAR FROM birthdate) - 1, ' years')::interval
        else 
            birthdate + concat(extract(YEAR from now()) - extract(YEAR FROM birthdate), ' years')::interval
    end as last_birthdate
from tab
```